# How to get external text file in root and append it to p element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm working on a project which needs to retrieve the data in a .txt file and append it's data to a p element.

This is my HTML:

```
    <p id="displayName"></p>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList) {
  /*Great success! All the File APIs are supported.*/
} else {
  alert('error: The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function errorHandler(e) {
  var msg = '';

  switch (e.code) {
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error';
      break;
  };

  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}

function onInitFs(fs) {

  fs.root.getFile('untitled.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {

    // Get a File object representing the file,
    // then use FileReader to read its contents.
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        var txtArea = document.createElement('textarea');
        txtArea.value = this.result;
        document.getElementById("displayName").appendChild(txtArea);
      };

      reader.readAsText(file);
    }, errorHandler);

  }, errorHandler);

}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, onInitFs,
  errorHandler);
```

The line above throws an error. How should i go about fixing this?

Help would be highly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: What error does it throw?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload), there is no `onloadend` property in `FileReader`, just an `onload` property. It has a `loadend` event, but it's not available as a property, so you need to use `addEventListener`.

```
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function(e) {
    var txtArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    txtArea.value = this.result;
    document.getElementById("displayName").appendChild(txtArea);
};
```